# VB.Net TreeView NodeMouseClick middle mouse button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, treeview, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I have been using the NodeMouseClick event to handle left and right clicks on my TreeNodes for a while. Now I want to add an effect to middle clicking as well, but the NodeMouseClick event doesn't seem to fire on a middle click. Is this a known bug, or should it work fine and I'm just doing something wrong? If it is a bug (or just intended to function this way), how can I make a middle click on a TreeNode do something specific with that node?

Here's a bit of my code:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeMouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Call nodeLeft(e.Node)
    ElseIf e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle Then
        Call nodeMiddle(e.Node)
    ElseIf e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        Call nodeRight(e.Node)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: By design, the native TreeView control only reports left and right button clicks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this version:

```
Public Class MyTreeView
  Inherits TreeView

  Private Const WM_MBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H207

  Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    If m.Msg = WM_MBUTTONDOWN Then
      Dim p As Point = Me.PointToClient(MousePosition)
      Dim mouseNode As TreeNode = Me.GetNodeAt(p)
      If mouseNode IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.OnNodeMouseClick(New TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs(mouseNode, MouseButtons.Middle, 1, p.X, p.Y))
      End If
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

It will fire the NodeMouseClick event with the middle value set for the Button property.  It won't select the node though.  To do that, add the line `Me.SelectedNode = mouseNode` above the OnNodeMouseClick call.

Comment: I'm holding out on my +1 until you change the magic number into a meaningfully-named constant. :-) The context provided by the question is the only way I can guess it's `WM_MBUTTONDOWN`.

Comment: @CodyGray Magic number removed.